# On Motzei Shabbat/Tisha B'Av how is the Havdalah candle extinguished?

Tags: tisha-bav, havdalah, fire-burning

Since during a normal Havdalah you would extinguish the Havdalah candle in the wine but none is being used because Tisha B'Av starts Motzei Shabbat, what is the proper manner with which it should be put out?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17405/759

Answer (score 3):

Mishna Berura 556:1 says that the candle used to say the Bracha of Borai Meorai Haish on Motzei Shabbos that is Tisha B'Av should be used for reading Aicha. Thus the proper manner is to not  put out the candle.

Comment: And what happens after Eikha?

Comment: @doubleaa Put it out by stubbing it, blowing it or leave it on.

Comment: Does the Mishna Berura say that? If so it should be in your post as the only thing that answers the question of how the candle is put out.

Comment: @DoubleAA "how the candle is put out" - It seems that he answered it. It is **not** put out after Eicha, as I am understanding this answer. It seems to say that it stays on until it extinguishes itself, whenever that is.

Comment: @danf that's the exact opposite of what the OP himself said he means in his comment above